# Doing dpkg-reconfigure wireshark-common inside of a Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, wireshark, dpkg, non-interactive

How do you do `dpkg-reconfigure wireshark-common` inside of a Dockerfile?

My Docker file contains:
`RUN apt-get install wireshark --yes`

But the `--yes` does not effect the `dpkg-reconfigure wireshark-common` step so it is not obvious to me how to answer Yes or even No to the on screen question `Should non-superusers be able to capture packets?`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the `yes` command.

```
RUN yes | dpkg-reconfigure wireshark-common
```

Another try you can do is:

```
RUN echo "y" | dpkg-reconfigure wireshark-common
```

Not sure now what is wireshark asking for on dpkg-reconfigure... but using this technique you can send a "y" or a "1" or whatever you need.

Another possible solution based on your comments here:

```
RUN apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y wireshark
```

With this last one, you'll skip any interactive post-install configuration steps.

Comment: Thanks for this.  It would seem to work if wireshark-common was installed.  The Dockerfile is doing `RUN apt-get install wireshark --yes` which in turn runs the `dpkg-reconfigure wireshark-common` command.  I ether need the Yes to propagate into the  `dpkg-reconfigure` subcommand or I need to get the `apt-get install wireshark` command to not run `dpkg-reconfigure`.

Answer (score 1):

With the first answer I was not able to run tshark as non-root.
Here my solution which accepts the "yes" answer by 'dpkg-reconfigure wireshark-common' so you can run tshark as normal user:

```
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y tshark
RUN yes yes | DEBIAN_FRONTEND=teletype dpkg-reconfigure wireshark-common
RUN usermod -a -G wireshark yourUserName
```

Replace "yourUserName" with the user which shall be allowed to run tshark.